# _data[] is defined at where in magento?

Tags: php, magento, header, graphical-logo

I saw following codes in header.php,

```
_data['logo_src']
_data['logo_alt']
```

Where this are defined? And How I can edit this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the data in `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header` Object.

**logo_src:**

It represent image path for logo which defined from Admin in `Logo Image Src` Field at `System->Configuration->General->Design->Header`

**logo_alt:**

It represent alt text for logo which defined from Admin in `Logo Image Alt` Field at `System->Configuration->General->Design->Header`

Values are store in `core_cofig_data` table with path value `design/header/logo_src` and `design/header/logo_alt` respectively ,so to change them pragmatically you can run such code

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$code  = $store->getCode();
$config = Mage::getConfig();
$config->setNode("stores/$code/design/header/logo_src", 'value_to_set');
```